# Do errors in BoundField.errors and BoundField.help_text need to be escaped in a template in Django?

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates

Do errors in `BoundField.errors` and `BoundField.help_text` need to be escaped in a template in Django? My guess is yes because both the errors and the `help_text` are no place for HTML code. However, I am a bit confused after I saw the following two snippets of code in the documentation of Django.

Snippet A:

```
{% if form.subject.errors %}
    <ol>
    {% for error in form.subject.errors %}
        <li><strong>{{ error|escape }}</strong></li>
    {% endfor %}
    </ol>
{% endif %}
```

Snippet B:

```
{% for field in form %}
    <div class="fieldWrapper">
        {{ field.errors }}
        {{ field.label_tag }} {{ field }}
        {% if field.help_text %}
        <p class="help">{{ field.help_text|safe }}</p>
        {% endif %}
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```

(Snippet A can be found at near [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/forms/#rendering-form-error-messages), and Snippet B can be found near [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/forms/#looping-over-the-form-s-fields))

For Snippet A, I don't think the `escape` filter is needed because Django's default template engine escapes the string representation of any variable value by default.

For Snippet B, I don't think the `safe` filter should be used because `help_text` is no place for any HTML code.

Is my understanding incorrect, or are these two snippets of demo code in Django's documentation problematic the ways I indicated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Escape-Filter

```
{% if form.subject.errors %}
    <ol>
    {% for error in form.subject.errors %}
        <li><strong>{{ error|escape }}</strong></li>
    {% endfor %}
    </ol>
{% endif %}
```

This snippet from the docs is a bit misleading, I think. As you stated before, yes, usually auto-escaping takes place. The documentation ([here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/templates/builtins/#escape)) of `escape` says:

> Applying escape to a variable that would normally have auto-escaping applied to the result will only result in one round of escaping being done. So it is safe to use this function even in auto-escaping environments.

This could be useful if you have no control about the parent templates and somewhere in the HTML is `{% autoescape off %}`. But I think this is a very anusual case.

#### Safe-Filter

The `safe`-filter is the opposite. It tells django that no escaping is needed there, if autoescaping is enabled. So because the help text has usually no characters which needs to get escaped, the author of this snippet rates it as safe content and tells django not to use autoescaping - if it is enabled at all.

```
{% for field in form %}
    <div class="fieldWrapper">
        {{ field.errors }}
        {{ field.label_tag }} {{ field }}
        {% if field.help_text %}
        <p class="help">{{ field.help_text|safe }}</p>
        {% endif %}
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```

From my experience, I see no reason why to go without autoescaping and therefore no need for these to filters most of the time.